# Is there a way to stop PyCharm from flagging "from pythoncom import com_error" as an error?

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to update a Python script that makes calls to a COM object.  Instead of catching plain vanilla Exception objects, I want to catch com_error objects.  I am using:

```
from pythoncom import com_error
```

My script works, but PyCharm underlines com_error in red, calling it an unresolved reference, and if I try to use any members of the com_error class in my code, they are also flagged unresolved.

Is there some way to get PyCharm to find the pythoncom or pywintypes modules?

I'm using the 32-bit version of Python 3.7.  I found the file pythoncom.py in C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages.

Comment: I would actually try to solve this problem instead of telling pycharm to shut up (which can be done via 'Alt + Space'). Try to figure out why pycharm does not find `com_error`.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. PyCharm doesn't like something, and I want to know why.  Presumably, PyCharm is telling me that I did something wrong, even though Python can work with what I have.  PyCharm probably knows more than I do, so I want to find the fix.  I don't want to merely "tell PyCharm to shut up".

Comment: Does pycharm not find the `pythoncom` module or did it not find the `com_error`?

Comment: It appears that com_error is not found.  That's what's underlined, not "pythoncom".

Comment: If you go into the `pythoncom` file (Strg+b on the Name), and then search for `com_error` (or 'class com_error'), do you find any global definitions?

Comment: I presume you're referring to the Control key.  I hit Ctrl+b and a little message pops up saying "Cannot find definition to go to".